# PHP Simple xml parser objects

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Hi Friends I have a quick question tried searching on google but not able to find some thing.
Here is a print_r of a de-serialized xml object

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [id] => 1234
    [user] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 123
            [title] => Mr
            [first-name] => Test
            [last-name] => Test
            [status] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => active
                    [type] => user_status
                    [is-enabled] => true
                )
        )
    [start-date] => 2016-02-09T10:27:29.561Z
    [expire-date] => 2016-02-09T11:27:29.561Z
    [auth-token] => 12333423423
)
```

How can I access the properties with - in them? 
I believe - is not valid character in PHP variables.

Comment: try it with $obj->{'start-date'}

Comment: Thank you @ChetanAmeta it worked